# open graph image being overwritten by gravatar logo?

Tags: facebook, sharing, open-graph

example page;
http://www.c-art.org.uk/2011/07/01/jenny-abbot/

some reason the gravatar image is overwriting the posts featured image thumb (100x100). Nnot sure how its doing it! How can i get rid of it?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Jenny Abbot" />
<meta property="og:description" content="C-Art — Cumbria Artist Open Studios, Jenny Abbot Artist Index PaintingC-Art"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://c-art.modernactivity.co.uk/?p=1254"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.c-art.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/Summer-at-Sea-Wood-100mm-100x100.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="C-Art"/>
```

best, dc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a Facebook share button on [the page you are talking about](http://www.c-art.org.uk/2011/07/01/jenny-abbot/), but I ran this through [Facebook Lint](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http://www.c-art.org.uk/2011/07/01/jenny-abbot/) and it appears that your Open Graph meta tags are working correctly.

Comment: odd - the facbook logo is below the small paragraph on the left. Its link is http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.c-art.org.uk%2F2011%2F07%2F01%2Fjenny-abbot%2F&t=Jenny+Abbot. Also true about lint showing the correct content. Maybe it was a wordpress cache issue?! Do you see the tree painting? Cheers Chris.

Comment: Yes, I see the tree painting when I share on FB.  It's not WP. FB caches, so if you added the og tags after it had cached your page, it might have picked a random image.  You can always run FB Lint to make facebook inspect your page.

Answer (score 0):

[This post on wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/facebook-feeding-showing-only-g-gravatar-image) was useful especially at the end, where you can view page source to see if the gravatar is being called and hence facebook is picking this up when posting from twitter feed, and displaying a blue gravatar instead of the post image. I switched off the plugin share and follow, however now I need to trouble shoot this.

Comment: Please add the exact same steps (to reproduce it) to your answer here as well.